# accessing timepicker-pop values populated using ng-repeat from ngController

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create cron setup for each day for a particular time using timepicker-pop.
my html template looks like this.

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="day in week">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>
            <input id="{{day.name}}" type="checkbox"> {{day}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>
            <input id="{{day}}_all" type="checkbox"> 24Hr
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <timepicker-pop input-time="time1" class="input-group" show-meridian='showMeridian'> 
        </timepicker-pop>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <timepicker-pop input-time="time2" class="input-group" show-meridian='showMeridian'> 
        </timepicker-pop>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to set up my controller

```
$scope.week = [{
    id: "Sun",
    st: new Date(),
    et: new Date()
}, {
    id: "Mon",
    st: new Date(),
    et: new Date()
}, {
    id: "Tue",
    st: new Date(),
    et: new Date()
}, {
    id: "Wed",
    st: new Date(),
    et: new Date()
}, {
    id: "Thu",
    st: new Date(),
    et: new Date()
}, {
    id: "Fri",
    st: new Date(),
    et: new Date()
}, {
    id: "Sat",
    st: new Date(),
    et: new Date()
}];
```

and use `{{day.st}}` and `{{day.et}}` for input_time in timepicker-pop but i am facing parsing error saying invalid token.

now i have made the names as `time1` and `time2` for `st` and `et` which display properly.

I am now not getting how to access each time when selected inside my controller.
Can anyone please provide me a solution.

Hope my description is clear.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok Michelem. let me try again to explain. I am trying to trigger an event to happen at a time that the user can select. So, my form will be having name of the day and if he wants to all day to run he can select 24hrs or can provide start and end time.  Now then i have created the form, i am unable to set the names of each field to access in my controller. the timepicker is not allowing me to use any bind variable for each day start and end time.  To get the form displayed i have set time1 and time2 to Date object. if the user selects multple days and time, how can i accessing in my controller.